# Image hash fingerprint collision (dHash)

Tags: image, hash, fingerprint

I'm using dHash (http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?url=archives/529-Kind-of-Like-That.html) in a veeery large set of images. 
The default resize size is 8 pixels:

```
def dhash(image, hash_size=8):
    """
    Difference Hash computation.
    following http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/529-Kind-of-Like-That.html
    @image must be a PIL instance.
    """
    image = image.convert("L").resize((hash_size + 1, hash_size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    pixels = numpy.array(image.getdata(), dtype=numpy.float).reshape((hash_size + 1, hash_size))
    # compute differences
    diff = pixels[1:, :] > pixels[:-1, :]
    return ImageHash(diff)
```

If we apply this algorithm do a large number of images do I not will get collisions due to the short hash fingerprint?

What would be the best hash_size? Is not more accurate as larger is the hash_size? Is it 8 because some specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently looked at the statistics of several million dhashes. The distribution is quite close to uniformity, i. e. at least my dataset did not have any patterns, such as images tending to be brighter in the upper half, etc.

That means the probability of collisions approaches the binomial case with independence of each bit. IIRC correctly, 8x8 pixels means the hash you are saving is 64bits. There are 2**64 = 1.8 x 10**19 possible hashes, which is a lot. The birthday paradox knocks us down again by a square root, so you would expect to see your first collision with your 4 billionth image.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a secondary DHash by calculating the differences across the Y value as opposed to the X value as you're doing here:

```
pixels[1:, :] > pixels[:-1, :]
```

Using two DHashes you can reduce the possibility of collisions (but not eliminate them).

If you want to take it a step further you can even add PHash (much more accurate but a slower algorithm) into the mix. In this case, if you have any collisions then create a PHash of both images to compare them.

Last but not least, you can compute your hashes using bigger images than 8x9. This will reduce the false positives however it will also increase the chances of overlooking an image.